# Benzannulation of 18-crown-6

Tags: organic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, ethers

I know crown ethers can be used to complex metal ions.
**Question**: What important properties do 18-crown-6 change during the benzannulation from 18-crown-6 to DB18C6 (dibenzo-18-crown-6)? How do these change?
(Disclaimer: I know that DB18C6 does not necessary to be synthesised from 18C6)
Motivation: I saw that some complexations of metal ions use 18C6, but some of the other use DB18C6.
Thoughts and Research: As crown ethers are used to make size-specific ions complexes, the sizes of the hole in the ethers are important. But the benzannulation does not change the size, so I suggest that the process changes the equilibrium constant of $\ce{M(ether)X_n}$ or the rate of complexation. Investigated by [this article](https://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/pdf/10.1246/bcsj.52.1027), the distribution constant between polar phase and non-polar phase increases significantly and the equilibrium constant in non-polar phase increases. I understand the former because of the property of benzene ring. But how can the latter one happen? Are there another reasons why DB18C6 is chosen?

Comment: Of course does the geometry of the crown ether change! Four sp3 carbon atoms are now sp2!